# Rotating div onClick - cycle through various degrees (wheel of fortune)

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, css-transitions

The effect I'm trying to achieve is upon clicking a button a circle made up of 8 triangles spins around. When it stops the triangle at the top of the circle is selected. Then a fancybox overlay relative to the selected segment is opened (this last part doesn't work yet). The order the segments are selected appears random to the user but it can be preset as I've done in the CSS (currently: 3rd > 6th > 1st > 8th > 2nd > 5th > 7th > 4th).

I've created a codepen to show my current progress on this which you can see by visiting the link below as its quite hard to explain.

```
http://codepen.io/moy/pen/DrbAL
```

On clicking the 'Spin' button the circle rotates 3 times (1080 degrees) + an additional 270 degrees so the 3rd list-item is positioned at the top of the div - this works fine.

My 1st question is: On the 2nd click of the button, the circle needs to rotate 3 times again and then a bit more to position the next selected list-item/segment (6) at the top of the div and so on for each of the remaining items. Is there a way to do this without having to add 1080 to the amount the circle has already rotated?? So the value is always `1080deg` + the additional amount the circle needs to rotate to position the relevant segment at the top of the div. Otherwise the last item's value is going to be something like 10000 degrees! If this has to be done I guess I'll have to live with it and get my maths hat on.

The 2nd question is: Once the circle has finished rotating, how can I display the related fancybox overlay? The ID's are currently the title of each overlay but could easily be overlay-1, overlay-2, etc to match the classes of spin-1, spin-2 set on the spinning wheel after each spin.

Thanks, hope someone can help!

Comment: are you following a pattern? or the wheel should spin randomly?

Comment: It should 'appear' random. I guess in an ideal world it would be completely random but never select a segment that had been used before. Once all 8 had been selected that would be the end. BUT in reality no one will really do this again/more than once, so having a set order so its the same whenever someone uses it would be totally fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this question very interesting because I worked on a similar project some time ago so this is my input. First, I would suggest you to use the Julian Shapiro's [velocity](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) plugin for your animations, which will give you some of the following advantages :

- Less and cleaner code without the clutter (for both css and javascript)
- Javascript animations that are (arguable) faster than CSS3 animations. Read [this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation) for more
- You don't have to toggle css classes back and forth to achieve your animations (and you don't have to manually pre-set and calculate how many degrees to spin within your css rules)

With velocity, spinning your wheel can be done as simple as  :

```
$(".wheel").velocity({
    rotateZ : "-" + {degree} + "deg" // "-" minus to spin counterclockwise, remove otherwise
});
```

The *velocity* plugin has a full set of API options that you can explore [here](http://julian.com/research/velocity/). Of course, you need an algorithm to calculate the new value of the `degree` variable on every `click`.

Now, if I understood correctly you have two questions :

- How to calculate the amount of degrees to spin to wheel and the stop in the next wanted position.
- How to determine what was the selected segment (on top of the wheel) regardless whether it was preset or randomly selected and then launch the corresponding fancybox.

I will start answering the **second** question with the following algorithm :

```
_target = (_deg - (360 * parseInt(_deg / 360))) / 45;
```

where `_target` is the javascript `index` of the selected segment and `_deg` the amount of degrees we had spun the wheel from the previous position to the current.

How it works :

Following your example above, the initial state of your wheel is segment No. 1 (Commercial Awareness) and from there you need to move to No. 3 (Team Work), so it means spinning the wheel 3 times (1080 degrees) + 2 more segments of 45 degrees each (90 degrees) = `1170 degrees` rotation.

so, applying that value to the algorithm :

```
_target = (1170 - (360 * parseInt(1170 / 360))) / 45;
_target = (1170 - (360 * parseInt(3.25))) / 45;
_target = (1170 - (360 * 3)) / 45;
_target = (1170 - (1080)) / 45;
_target = (90) / 45;
_target = 2;
```

If you consider that in javascript the first element of a group has `index=0`, the second is `index=1`, the third is `index=2`, etc. `_target = 2` actually points to the third segment (Team Work). This algorithm works regardless how many degrees you have spun the wheel.

Then firing fancybox is simple:

```
$(".fancybox").eq(_target).trigger("click");
```

the code above assumes you have initialized fancybox somewhere in your script like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({ // API options });
```

---

Now, for the **first** question I see 3 possible algorithms that you can set in a separated function to call after button `click` :

### Sequential :

Returns a patterned order (advances 3 segments each `click`) like 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6 ... then loops. Every segment is shown at least once before the loop so :

```
function ordSequential() {
    // order : 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6 ... then loops
    return _deg = _deg + (45*3) + 1080;
};
```

it assumes an initial value of `_deg = 0`. Notice you can always change the factor `3` to alter the pattern.

So having the amount of degrees we will spin the wheel, we can use *velocity* to :

- reset all segments' opacity to `1`
- spin the wheel
- set selected segment's opacity to `0.4`
- fire the selected segment's corresponding fancybox

the full code

```
// sequential order
// advances 3 segments each click
var _target, _deg = 0;
function ordSequential() {
    // order : 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6 ... then loops
    return _deg = _deg + (45*3) + 1080;
};
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".skills-wheel .btn").on("click", function (e) {
        // select algorithm sequential, random or preset :
        ordSequential();
        _target = (_deg - (360 * parseInt(_deg / 360))) / 45;
        // start animation
        // reset opacity of all segments to 1
        $(".fancybox").parent("li").velocity({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            complete: function () {
                $(".wheel").velocity({
                    rotateZ: "-" + _deg + "deg"
                }, {
                    duration: 3000,
                    complete: function (elements) {
                        // after spinning animation is completed, set opacity of target segment's parent
                        $(".fancybox").parent("li").eq(_target).velocity({
                            opacity: 0.4
                        }, {
                            duration: 100,
                            // after opacity is completed, fire targeted segment in fancybox
                            complete: function () {
                                $(".fancybox").eq(_target).trigger("click");
                            } // third animation completed
                        }); // nested velocity 2
                    } // second animation completed
                }); // nested velocity 1
            } // first animation completed
        }); // velocity
        return false;
    }); // click

    // initialize fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth: "85%"
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/41bcmpa6/)**

**Notice** the use of nested* velocity functions inside its `complete` callback

> *** EDIT** : if you are using Velocity's UI pack, you could use the function [`.RunSequence()`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#uiPack) to make nested animation sequences much more manageable. See updated <kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b5nx6yzn/)**</kbd> using this method. Make sure you use the latest version of Velocity.js and UI pack (v1.1.0 as today [Oct 8, 2014]) http://cdnjs.com/libraries/velocity

### Preset :

Returns a preset order as in your example above

```
3rd > 6th > 1st > 8th > 2nd > 5th > 7th > 4th
```

The code is basically the same but the algorithm a little bit more complex. First we need to preset the order within an array along with other support variables:

```
var presetPos = [3, 6, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4],
    presetInit = true,
    spin_count = 0;
```

**Notice** the `presetPos` array contains the actual segment number and not the javascript `index`. Also notice the use of the flag `presetInit`, which tells if the wheel is in its initial state (we'll switch it to `false` after the first spin)

The sauce of the *preset* algorithm is to calculate the difference (in degrees) between the `current` and the `next` segment in the array so we will know how many degrees the wheel need to spin :

```
function ordPreset() {
    // initial state?
    if (presetInit) {
        presetInit = false;
        return _deg = _deg + ((presetPos[spin_count] - 1) * 45) + 1080;
    } else {
        var _current = presetPos[spin_count];
        var _next = presetPos[spin_count > 6 ? 0 : spin_count + 1];
        var _diff = _next - _current;
        spin_count = spin_count > 6 ? 0 : ++spin_count;
        return _deg = _deg + (_diff * 45) + 1080;
    };
};
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x7g9kc2k/)**

### Random :

Returns a random order in the 0-7 range.

The random algorithm is pretty simple. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for reference.

```
function ordRandom() {
    return _deg = _deg + ((Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 1 + 1)) + 0) * 45) + 1080;
};
```

However the logic inside the `click` method is a little bit more complex. In your ideal world the selected segment should be completely random but never select a segment that has been used before. Once all `8` have been selected that would be the end (the button will stop spinning the wheel).

The are several factors to consider : First, we need an array to tell what segments have never been used.

```
var _index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

**Notice** this array is about the `index` of each segment.

Additionally we need a *flag* that let us loop (using `while`) through the random selection until we find one `index` that has never been used.

```
var _repeatRandom = true;
```

Then, it's important to remove the random selected `index` from the array using the `.splice()` method to make sure we won't use it again.

the code for the click event :

```
$(".skills-wheel .btn").on("click", function (e) {
    // select algorithm sequential, random or preset :
    // if random order, don't repeat the same
    _repeatRandom = _index.length == 0 ? false : true;
    // loop until find one that has never been used
    while (_repeatRandom) {
        ordRandom();
        _target = (_deg - (360 * parseInt(_deg / 360))) / 45;
        var _inArray = $.inArray(_target, _index);
        if (_inArray > -1) {
            // target is in the array
            _repeatRandom = false; // break while loop
            _index.splice(_inArray, 1); // remove segment from array so it won't be repeated

            // start animation
            // reset opacity of all segments to 1
            $(".fancybox").parent("li").velocity({
                opacity : 1
            }, {
                duration : 100,
                complete : function () {
                    $(".wheel").velocity({
                        rotateZ : "-" + _deg + "deg"
                    }, {
                        // addtional settings and callback
                        duration : 3000,
                        complete : function (elements) {
                            // after spinning animation is completed, set opacity of target segment's parent
                            $(".fancybox").parent("li").eq(_target).velocity({
                                opacity : 0.4
                            }, {
                                duration : 100,
                                // after opacity is completed, fire targeted segment in fancybox
                                complete : function () {
                                    $(".fancybox").eq(_target).trigger("click");
                                } // third animation completed
                            }); // nested velocity 2
                        } // second animation completed
                    }); // nested velocity 1
                } // first animation completed
            }); // velocity

        }; // if
    }; // while
    return false;
}); // click
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/090yncuu/)**

**LAST NOTES** :

- I removed the unnecessary css selectors and `transform` effects (`.wheel.spin-1`, `.wheel.spin-2`, `.wheel.spin-3` , etc.)
- there are many settings (like `duration` of the animations, etc.) you may want to adjust to your preferences and needs.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing, thanks a lot. So much detail! The only problem I had was when I changed the rotation so the wheel rotated clockwise (by removing the "-") instead the correct segments weren't selected. But I _think_ I may of sorted this by tweaking the `return _deg = _deg + (45*3) + 1080;` part of the code. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @user1406440 : as improvement, if you are using Velocity's UI pack, you could use the function [`.RunSequence()`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#uiPack) to make nested animation sequences much more manageable. See the sequential option of my answer updated with this method: **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/b5nx6yzn/)**. Make sure you use the latest version of Velocity.js and UI pack (v1.1.0 as today) http://cdnjs.com/libraries/velocity